# Will POSIX system(3) call to an asynchronous shell command return immediately?

Tags: c, linux, posix-api

For example, `system("sh /mydir/some-script.sh &")`

Comment: Why not try it and see?  That's likely faster than asking a question and waiting for people to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system("sh /mydir/some-script.sh &")
```

executes

```
/bin/sh -c 'sh /mydir/some-script.sh &'
```

`system` will return as soon as outer shell returns, which will be immediately after it launches the inner shell. Neither shell will wait for `some-script.sh` to finish.

```
$ cat some-script.sh
sleep 1
echo foo

$ /bin/sh -c 'sh some-script.sh &' ; echo bar ; sleep 2
bar
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the shell will fork the script and return immediately, but you don't have an easy way of knowing how and whether the script has ended.

The "proper" way to run such an asynchronous command would be to `fork(2)` your process, call `execve(2)` in the child with the binary set to `/bin/sh` and one of the arguments set to the name of your script, and poll the child periodically from the parent using the `waitpid(2)` system call with the `WNOHANG` option. When `waitpid` returns -1, you know that the script has ended and you can fetch its return code.

In fact, what `system(3)` does is almost the same with the only exception that the call to `waitpid` blocks until the process terminates.