# How to continue program after another window is opened

Tags: c++

So I am an amateur programmer, currently enrolled in my second semester of C++ (yesterday we learned about structs just to give you an idea of what I know...).

I am creating a simple program to help me file documents at my internship.

I am using a system command(yes I know its dangerous and a big security risk), to open a pdf in firefox so that I can see the file and know where to put it.

I have successfully opened firefox and opened the pdf.

However my program stops running until I close firefox.

My question is how do I continue my program at the same time?

Is there an easier way to display a pdf in an executable?

edit:
Here is the function I use to open the firefox window with the pdf in it:

void openPDFBrowser (char array[])
{

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.close();
outFile.open("PDF_browswer_handleScript.txt") ;
if(outFile.good())cout<<"OUTFILE GOOD" << endl;
outFile << "system("<<array<<")"<<endl;
system("PDF_browswer_handleScript.txt");
outFile.close();
```

}

the .txt file contails:    firefox C:\Scans\Attorney.pdf
where firefox references a .bat file which contains the location of firefox.exe
I will take any suggestions

it just seemed easier to use an external browser to handle the display of the pdf file, although I'm still working out this threading idea

Comment: Show us a some code. *Exactly* how do you open the pdf?

Comment: Here's how you make the call async: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666962/will-posix-system3-call-to-an-asynchronous-shell-command-return-immediately `add an ampersand &`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666962/will-posix-system3-call-to-an-asynchronous-shell-command-return-immediately

Comment: What college are you attending where you didn't learn about structs until the 2nd semester????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system` is a blocking command - meaning it will stop your execution until that function returns. The only way to do this is to create a separate thread (or to `fork` a separate process, as noted by [Chris Hayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813853/chris-hayes)), and to run the `system` (or `CreateProcess`, or `exec`) inside it, allowing main thread to continue.

Comment: To expand slightly - instead of a separate thread, you could also `fork` a new process and do the same thing.